# Angular, $route.current returning undefined, but $route has a .current property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a controller:

```
app.controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
   console.log($route);
   console.log($route.current)
}]);
```

But when I try to use `$route.current` I get undefined, I have no idea why as $route has the propety when I `console.log($route)`

[image]

I have

```
.when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/home',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      activeTab: 'home'
    }).
```

I need to access `$route.current.$$route.activeTab` so I can get the variable and set the appropriate class.

Full Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('PugIt', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/home',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      activeTab: 'home'
    }).
    when('/help', {
      templateUrl: '/help',
      controller: 'HelpController',
      activeTab: 'help'
    }).
    when('/donate', {
      templateUrl: '/donate',
      controller: 'DonateController',
      activeTab: 'donate'
    }).
    when('/server', {
      templateUrl: '/server',
      controller: 'ServerController',
      activeTab: 'server'
    }).
    when('/server/new', {
      templateUrl: '/server/new',
      controller: 'NewServerController',
      activeTab: 'serverNew'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {

}]);

app.controller('HelpController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {

}]);

app.controller('DonateController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {

}]);

app.controller('ServerController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {

}]);

app.controller('NewServerController', ['$scope', '$route', function($scope, $route) {
}]);

app.controller('NavbarController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $route.activeTab = $route.current.$$route.activeTab;
});
```

Which then sets the active class with:

```
 // Navbar
    <div ng-controller="NavbarController">
        <li ng-class="{'active': activeTab == 'home'}"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    </div>
    // End of Navbar
    <div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: I think that the object is not actually logged in this situation, rather the object **reference** is logged. Therefore, if the object reference is modified after the `console.log($route.current)` the console will show the updated object.

Comment: setTimeout()    ,   haha  - just kidding , I'm working on an app where that was the solution to everything

Comment: @Datsik, well, where exactly does this `NavbarController` "live"? Does it live outside of `ng-view`?

Comment: @NewDev Yes it does actually

Comment: @Datsik, then what is the "current route" you expect it to have?

Comment: @NewDev I guess the data from the Home controller :/

Comment: @Datsik, I don't understand. Do you just need to keep track of which route is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to keep track of your routes, you can definitely `$watch` for changes:

```
.controller('NavbarController', function($scope, $route) {
   $scope.$route = $route;
   $scope.$watch("$route.current.$$route.activeTab", function(v){
     $scope.activeTab = v;
   }
});
```

But this creates an unnecessary `$watch`. It's not too bad since it is only one, but it would be cleaner to listen to a `$routeChangeSuccess` event instead:

```
.controller('NavbarController', function($scope, $route) {
   $scope.$route = $route;
   $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous){
     $scope.activeTab = current.$$route.activeTab;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the current route is not set when the `NavController` is loaded.

What you can do in your `NavController` is to watch over `$route.current`, and 
when it gets set\changed, implement the logic in the watch handler

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
   return $route.current;
},function(newValue,oldValue) {
    //implement logic here
});
```